# PresentViewController from a presentedViewController is not showing navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, presentviewcontroller

I have three view controllers (vc1, vc2, vc3) and two navigation controllers (nav1, nav2).

- nav1 is the entry point of the storyboard.
- vc1 is the rootViewController of nav1.
- vc2 is the rootViewController of nav2.
- nav2 is presented from vc1 through nav1.

Now when I tried to present vc3 from vc2 through nav2, navigation bar is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to present your controller with navigationController.

```
ViewController *objVC  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewcontrollerid"];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:objVC];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: You mean to say each and every time I present a view controller I have to create a navigation controller?

Comment: @TapasPal Actually whenever you present `VC` its just like one `VC` is above previous VC thats it. Basically presented VC does not have any Nav Control but the previous `VC` have. So if you wanted Nav Cntrl in `VCB` then push `VCA` or find Nav Cntrl of VCA(as a parent of `VCB`) in VCB class.

Comment: No you need to check first if navigation controller exist then use it other create new one .

Comment: In the last case of my problem I have navigationController as I wrote `present vc3 from vc2 through nav2`

Comment: yes but if you present that controller with previous navigation controller it not display nav bar. so you need to present new navigation controller instead of controller.

Answer (score 0):

Now, the way iOS works, it will never give you an instance of your navigation controller in a presented view controller because **when you present a view controller, it is not added to the viewcontroller stack of the navigation controller.** 
The reason you can see the navigation controller in the other two is because your'e presenting the navigation controller itself and not view controller.